# How do you make a child div fit to its parent’s non-scroll width?

Tags: javascript, css

The parent div has overlflow: auto, and expanded by child2.

I want to set child1 width to fit the parent dive non-scroll area.
Here is a demo:

https://jsbin.com/hitasupawa/edit?html,output

Update:
Sorry for my poor description about the issue.
The parent’s size is dynamic. Let us assume, now the parent width is 500px, the parent has a scrollbar. There is about 400px content that does not have to scroll to view. I want to set child1’s width to 400px.

Let us suppose, the parent’s width increased to 550px, there is about 450px that does not need to scroll to view, and then I want to set the child to 450px.

If there is no pure css solution, I could add a piece JavaScript code to listen the resize event, but how do you get the width not including the scrolling area?

[image]

Thanks.

```
<style>
    .parent {
        border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
        height: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 400px;
    }



    .child1{
        border: 1px solid blueviolet;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .child2 {
        border: 1px solid blueviolet;
        height: 50px;
        width: 500px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

</style>

<div class="parent">
    parent

    <div class="child1">child2</div>

    <div class="child2">child2</div>



</div>
```

Comment: Not sure wwhat _ set child1 width to fit the parent dive non-scroll area_ means? Start with removing the `width` on that `div`.

Comment: removing its width should work

Comment: If you are assuming the scroll bar's size will be constant then you can just figure out what the size is to fit that area. What I'm guessing you want to do is have the width of child 1 auto adjust if the window is resized. I believe you can't do that without javascript.
If you are willing to add javascript, you could add an event listener on window resize to adjust the size of child 1.

Comment: Yes, that what I mean. Please see my update. thank you.

Comment: simply remove width parameter from `.child1` and `.child2` and they will fit their widths perfectly to the parent.

Comment: child2's width cannot be removed, that's why the parent must have a scrollbar. Thanks.